# How do I right justify columns in a file

Tags: sed, awk, justify

How do I right justify the columns of a file in awk, sed, or bash ?

My file is currently left justified and space delimited.

Can I used `printf` or `rev`?

Here is what my file looks like :

```
$ cat file
14,107     aaa  12,436  0.0  0  0  313  0  373
3,806,201  bbb  1,573   0.0  0  0  -25  0  -25
```

And using `rev` doesn't give me the output I'm looking for.

```
$rev file  | column -t | rev
14,107  aaa  12,436  0.0  0  0  313  0  373
3,806,201  bbb   1,573  0.0  0  0  -25  0  -25
```

Comment: If `rev` doesn't work for your data I would use python to format it however I don't think you example is representative of your actual problem and I don't want to play the revision game.

Comment: Why don't you also show our expected output.

Comment: `rev` wouldn't work if items in the first column have different lengths.  Padding a column and later stripping it away would work: `rev file|sed 's/$/ ./'|column -t|rev|sed 's/^...//'`.  By the way, I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: I have a good answer I'd like to post. This is not a duplicate. The linked question is about columns of a *fixed width*. In this question we have columns of variable width.

Answer (score 12):

In lieu of a specific example here is a general solution using a trick with `rev`:

```
$ cat file
a 10000.00 x
b 100 y
c 1 zzzZZ

$ rev file | column -t | rev
a  10000.00      x
b       100      y
c         1  zzzZZ
```

Where `column -t` is replaced by whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: +1. note that this will right-justify every column.

Comment: @glennjackman right, it sounds like that is what the OP is asking for. I have changed the example so the behaviour is better shown.

Comment: Will not work properly if the leftmost columns aren't all the same width, but clever nonetheless

Comment: To work around the requirement *»entries in the leftmost column must be of equal width«* you can insert a dummy column and remove it later: `sed 's/^/a\t/' file | rev | column -t | rev | cut -c3-`.